# Distinct values in ManyToManyField over a subset of objects in Django

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

In my models I have the classes `Book` and `Category` defined like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

What I want is the set of `Category` instances that are referenced in the `categories` field of a given queryset of `Book` instances.

I realize I can iterate through the queryset of books and gather the categories for each book but this seems inefficient to me as this could be stated in a single SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM myapp_book_categorys JOIN myapp_category ON myapp_book_categorys.category_id=myapp_category.id
WHERE myapp_book_categorys.book_id IN 
    (SELECT id FROM myapp_book WHERE ...);
```

Is the raw SQL the right way to go or there is a higher level solution comparable in efficiency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**: Okay, I didn't have a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) to test on before so I was guessing. New code!

```
books = Book.objects.filter(title__contains="T")
categories = Category.objects.filter(book__in=books).distinct()
```

Comment: Yes, pretty much that, except that the book id's have to be extracted from a queryset

Comment: I tried your solution and it gives me this error: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'book_set' into field.`

Comment: @Sergio You should be able to use the queryset in place of the list. Also, I'm not precisely sure what the [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/) would be named, so you might have to poke around to find that.

Comment: No, there isn't such a thing as a field_set available for ManyToManyField fields in a queryset :-(.

Comment: select_related is of no help here, it only retrieves ForeignKeys.

Comment: ..yeah, I was guessing there more than I should have. Actually made the models and poked around a bit, that should work now.

Answer (score 4):

You need to filter by the 'book' field:

```
book_ids = list(Book.objects.filter(...).values_list('id', flat=True)
categories_queryset = Category.objects.filter(book__in=book_ids).distinct()
```

Comment: Hey, you got there a lot more quickly than I did.

Comment: @matt-s, anyway I upvoted your answer, that was just missing the correct filter name...