# limiting __in lookup in django

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

i have are question about "__in" lookup in Django ORM.

So here is the example of code:

```
tags = [Tag.objects.get(name="sometag")]
servers = Server.objects.filter(tags__in=tags)[offset_from:offset_to]
server_infos = []
for server in servers:
    server_infos.append(query.last())
```

So here is the problem: we making about 60-70 sql requests for each server. But i want to do something like this:

```
tags = [Tag.objects.get(name="sometag")]
servers = Server.objects.filter(tags__in=tags)[offset_from:offset_to]
server_infos = ServerInfo.objects.filter(contains__in=servers)
assert servers.count() == server_infos.count()
```

Can i do this without raw sql request? All i need to understand is how to limit "__in" expression in Django to get only last value as in example above. Is it possible?

Update, my models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Server(models.Model):
    
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    port = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)    
    
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_server_online(self):
        query = ServerInfo.objects.filter(contains=self)
        if query.exists():
            return query.last().online
        return 0
    
    
class ServerInfo(models.Model):
    
    contains = models.ForeignKey(Server, \
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
    map = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    game = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    online = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    max_players = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
    outdated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    
    ping = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        
        return f"Current map {self.map} and current online {self.online}/{self.max_players}"
```

Comment: Can you post your models (especially the relational fields)? Tag, Server, ServerInfo.

Comment: @nigel222 did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that tags is `ManyToMany` and a server may be selected twice by two different tags. Also that a server may have >1 serverinfos, because it's a `ForeignKey` relation not a `OneToOne`.

Possibilities:

Make sure a server is returned only once in the queryset:

```
servers = Server.objects.filter(tags__in=tags).distinct()[offset_from:offset_to]
```

(or `distinct('pk')` ?)

Make sure only one `ServerInfo` instance is returned per server:

```
server_infos = ServerInfo.objects.filter(contains__in=servers).distinct('contains')
```

Or use `prefetch_related` in the Servers query, and then avoid subsequent queries by always referring to the `serverinfo` objects through the related name (default "serverinfo_set")

I absolutely hate "magic" default related names, and would always code one explicitly: `contains = models.ForeignKey(Server, ..., related_name='server_infos', ...)`

```
servers = Server.objects.filter(tags__in=tags).distinct(
    ).prefetch_related('serverinfo')[offset_from:offset_to]

for server in servers:
    server_info = server.serverinfo_set.first() 

    # or
    for info in server.serverinfo_set:
```

NB don't start applying filters to `serverinfo_set` if you don't want to hit the DB N times. Filter by iterating through what is presumably a short list, and which is already in memory in  the queryset anyway.

Comment: Thanks again! Just has set up everything. Making filter with "distinct" was are great idea

Comment: Now my page making 4 SQL requests instead of 60 :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should retrieve the data using two queries, one to get all the servers and the second one to get all the server infos using [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). When filtering on a `ManyToManyField` you have to use `distinct()` to [avoid duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026427/distinct-values-in-manytomanyfield-over-a-subset-of-objects-in-django).

```
servers = Server.objects.filter(
    tags__name="sometag").distinct().prefetch_related("server_info_set")

for server in servers:
    print(server.name)
    for info in server.server_info_set.all():
        print(info)
```

If you only want to retrieve one certain info per server you would have to provide a custom queryset to `prefetch_related()` using [`Prefetch()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) objects.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

servers = Server.objects.filter(       
 tags__name="sometag").distinct().prefetch_related(Prefetch('server_info_set', 
        queryset=ServerInfo.objects.filter(outdated=False), 
        to_attr="current_infos"
    )
)

for server in servers:
    print(server.name)
    for info in server.current_infos.all():
        print(info)
```